# Printing an array to an email

Tags: php, html

I'm having an issue getting my php code to take an array that I have created:

```
$size = array(
  $_POST['wyxs'],
  $_POST['wys'],
  $_POST['wym'],
  $_POST['wyl'],
  $_POST['wyxl'],
  $_POST['was'],
  $_POST['wam'],
  $_POST['wal'],
  $_POST['waxl']
);
```

and place that in an email sent from the server to myself as usuable data. As of right now, the email simply says `Size: Array`

This is the bit that populates the email contents:

```
$message = "You have received a new message from your website's contact form.\n\n"
  . "Here are the details:\n
    \nName: $name\n
    \nEmail: $email\n
    \nSize(s): $size\n
    \nPackage(s): $package";
```

I believe I need to use `json_encode()` but I don't know where to put that line. I've seen answers here for outputting as a txt file, but that's not what I'm after.

Error log reports :

> PHP Notice:  Array to string conversion in /home/bc8gq1bc8v7v/public_html/Orderscript.php on line 58

where as line 58 is the line `"\nSize(s): $size\n"`

I've tried placing the `json_encode()` line under the variable definition line. Also tried placing inside the `"\nSize(s)"` line. Neither worked.

Expected: Email to read `Size(s): 7 yxs`

Results: Email reads `Size(s): Array`

Edit: The 7 is arbitrary. That value could be any number 0-10 entered by a customer on the site on any given size/color choice of a shirt.

Edit 2: Website for reference www.harbourgraphicsfl.com/dcecubs,html

Edit 3: After spending all day staring at code I forgot to put .html at the end of the link above..

Comment: Why do you expect the array to be printed as `7 yxs`? Where does the number `7` come from?

Comment: The number 7 was arbitrary. Will add additional info... My apologies.

Comment: I still don't understand why you expect any number there? You're putting 9 form fields into the `$size` array, don't you want to print all of them?

Comment: Not necessarily. 7 would reference the quantity of item (wyxs) that a customer selected on the site. I'm probably going about the whole issue backwards, as this is my very first attempt at something like this.

Comment: But what about `$_POST['wys`]` and `$_POST['wym']` and all the other variables that you put into the array?

Comment: Those are each a separate item. There's a link in the original post to the site I'm currently working on. Each variable is a size/color with the option to input a number 0-10. Ultimately I have (without counting yet) about 50 variables I'll need to have emailed to me. Haven't crossed that bridge yet. I started with just two sets of data.

Comment: It sound like you need some kind of loop that goes through all the POST parameters, not an array.

Comment: If they're separate items, why are you putting them all into an array, and why are you trying to print the array? Just use `$size = $_POST['wyxs']`

Comment: I'm not sure the duplicate question you linked to really solves your problem. Have you looked at the email, does it really contain what you want?

Comment: email me @ design@harbourgraphics.net

Comment: Sorry, you ask here, we discuss here.

Comment: my apologies, the discussion was getting lengthy. Have you looked at the page url I posted in the original post?
The email as of now contains the values I entered into the selection boxes, but does not return the name of the box they were entered in, so I have half of what I want. The page I linked contained what I needed to make the error I posted go away, so it answered what I had asked. Also, your answer below works well as well. And I actually fixed my code to you implode method as it's cleaner.

Comment: I get a 404 Not Found error when I try to go to the URL in the question.

Comment: The error goes away but you don't get the desired result.

Comment: Correct. But this question was directly about getting an array to print to an email. Which it does. Now I have to figure out how to get it to label the information. As of now, it sends all the numbers I input into the numerical fields I have set, but it doesn't tell from which box it came from, I only get the number entered. Also, I fixed the url. I forgot to add .html to the end of it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
$size = json_encode(array($_POST['wyxs'],$_POST['wys'],$_POST['wym'],$_POST['wyl'],$_POST['wyxl'],
                          $_POST['was'],$_POST['wam'],$_POST['wal'],$_POST['waxl']));
```

The email will then contain something like:

```
Size(s): ["foo","bar","baz",...]
```

Or you could use `implode()`:

```
$size = implode(", ", array($_POST['wyxs'],$_POST['wys'],$_POST['wym'],$_POST['wyl'],$_POST['wyxl'],
                            $_POST['was'],$_POST['wam'],$_POST['wal'],$_POST['waxl']));
```

and the email will contain:

```
Size(s): foo, bar, baz, ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello you can get the value $_POST['wyxs'] for the index 0 , like so :

```
$size[0]
```

You can access any of the elements by the index, starting with 0;

```
$size[0];$size[1];$size[2] ...
```

This :

```
PHP Notice: Array to string conversion in /home/bc8gq1bc8v7v/public_html/Orderscript.php on line 58" where as line 58 is the line "\nSize(s): $size\n"
```

is showing cause $size is an array and you're trying to put it as a string here:

```
\nSize(s): $size\n
```